# How to reply to "you ok" in British?

Tags: british-english, politeness, contemporary-english

I recently shifted in UK and started to work, here people always say "you ok?" When I am in kitchen or I am working and they pass by. How should i respond to it. Is it rude to simply say I m good or fine instead of asking them back about if they are ok too? Or what to ask?

Comment: That would be strange for someone coming from the states, since in America the question presumes that you are injured or emotionally burdened somehow. If you like the person you should engage them in conversation, ask about their family, etc. if you dislike the person then you should icily reply that you are OK and then turn your head away.

Comment: If, as they sometimes do, they ask *You all right ?*; you can astound them with your fluency and wit by replying *No, I'm half left*.

Comment: 'Fine thanks. You?'

Comment: Maybe you look tired, or miserable? Otherwise take it as a [pleasantry](https://www.google.it/search?q=pleasantry&oq=pleasantry&aqs=chrome..69i57&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8), and respond: "Yeah, and you?"

Comment: I would say: “I recently ***moved*** to **the** UK”. You don't normally use the verb *shift* when you emigrate or move to a different country.

Comment: The next time you see them, be sure to ask them "u ok m8?" before they ask you. Add their answers to your repertoire.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reply is just:

- OK?

It's not:

- I'm doing great thanks: I got a pay rise last month ....

It would work a bit like "How ya doin?" [in this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5cIqRzum528).

And here's [how not to do it](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9BdSoLE8ZeU).

A typical exchange might be:

- A: You ok?
- B: Ok? How's it going?
- A: Yeah, good cheers  ...
- B: Good ...
  -

Comment: It is clearly the modern equivalent of "How are you?"; old etiquette books are full of warnings against replying to that by *actually saying how you are feeling*.

Comment: @TimLymington Exactly so!

Answer (score 1):

I would just say, "Gooood! You?"

Answer (score 1):

Depends how it's being asked. If it's inquisitive, as in you're doing something and they want to know if you're OK. They're generally asking if you need help.

But in the situations you've described, it'll most likely be a cue to engage in smalltalk. If you say "I'm good thanks, how's things on your end?" and they stick around, it was asked to engage in conversation. In which case you should address their reply or just ask how their day has been.

Sometimes however it's said to break the awkward silence, when accidental eye contact has been made or to acknowledge your presence. In which case you can just nod or say "Fine thanks".